# Measuring apparently fake voltage

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

**UPDATE 1**

I'm leaving the stuff below intact, even though it's of no interest anymore now I guess: With device M1/RLY1 totally disconnected I thought I'd take a couple more measurements.

With the breaker for that circuit (P/N) being live and everything else disconnected I am still measuring at V:

- P/N =~ 127V --> same thing as before
- P/GND = N/GND =~ 0V

With the breaker switched off I am measuring this:

- P/N =~ 0V
- P/GND = N/GND =~ 10V

Now the question becomes, I guess, where is all of this connected to? In fact this circuit comes from an RCBO, connected to one of the three phases immediately after the electrical meter and before going to the distribution panels.

---

Take a look at the following diagram:

[image: circuit]

For your understanding:

- M1 switches RLY1 (RLY1 is an electromechanical relay inside M1): if M1 is off (or on and decides to open RLY1), RLY1 is open
- For that circumstance, and in order to bypass RLY1, there is SW1 which can be closed manually
- V is a multimeter connected to the plug where the device (consumer/load) is usually connected to

The block diagram of M1 can be found [here](http://shop1.luftdruckwaechter.de/shop/media/pdf/fa/8d/e9/E-Plan-Luftdruckwaechter-P4-Multi.pdf), and RLY1 is actually part of it (that's what the dotted lines in my diagram are for) (consider it one of the relays between contacts 1&2, or 3&4, ...).

If M1 is off, thus RLY1 open, and SW1 is also open, I am measuring ~127 Volts (of 230 volts normally) using V (multimeter). In fact SW1 doesn't matter at all and when this bypass is disconnected, it behaves the same (I just wanted to mention everything).

If I now connect some power supply (input 100-240V) instead of V, and use the multimeter V to measure the output voltage of said power supply, there is none. (The power supply has been tested and is working properly.)

This leads me to the conclusion that this is a fake voltage disappearing at the slightest hint of any loading. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Your diagram is confusing. What is M1, M2? And what is R1 and R2? "R" usually designates a resistor but you drew it as a switch.

Comment: You'll need to use the "edit" button to substantially re-state this if it is going to remain open.  It sounds though like you may be seeing with a high-impedance voltmeter any one of several ways in which (in particular AC) voltages can be coupled, induced, or leaked at minuscule currents, so that the voltage disappears when any meaningful load is applied.  This could be anything of intentional capacitors, parallel wire runs, electronic switches that are never fully "off", etc.

Comment: R1 is a relay (electrically operated by M1). R2 is indeed a stupid manual switch.

Comment: And what does "consumer" mean in your context? Is it a load? Why would there be an output voltage at M2? What is it? All very confused.

Comment: Usually M2 is an active device consuming electric power, yes. For the tests M2 is disconnected of course, and the measurements are taken on the plug it's normally connected to.

Comment: what does this mean? `R1 is potential-free`

Comment: But you said there is no output voltage from M2. Why would there be?

Comment: Sorry, but having "M1" be a *switch* and "M2" be a *load* just isn't going to fly.  You need to have a logical systematization, or better yet draw an actual schematic with quasi-standard symbols.

Comment: @Marki: There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. There are switches, relays and you can use something like a lamp for your "consumer".

Comment: @ChrisStratton As I said: R1 is a relay (electrically operated by M1, which needs its own power).

Comment: why are you marking `X` and `Y` when the two are the same point

Comment: I think you mean that R1 is the contact of a relay inside M1. If R2 is a switch then convention is to call it SW1 or SW2, etc. 'R' is universally a resistor. Use RLY for relay.

Comment: @Marki, please give a physical description of R1. describe what it actually is. (mechanical, electronic, etc).

Comment: What a mess. I think I will move on.

Comment: @jsotola: Just making sure. See the side question ;-)

Comment: @Transistor: yes, R1 is the contact of a relay inside M1

Comment: You've been a bit slow in fixing your question. It is now closed. Draw a proper schematic using standard component designations, answer all the points raised in the comments and edit them into your question. If you fix it properly we will vote to reopen.

Comment: this makes no sense `RLY1 is potential-free = no power is given to it by M1` ... the relay contact has power supplied by `P` ... if the contact is open and there is a load connected at the output, then there is full line voltage across the contacts

Comment: you still have not answered my question about the physical description of R1

Comment: I'm impressed by you Marki for steering off from the norm and trying to make us conform to your *standard*. Truly fascinating.

Comment: @jsotola You mean RLY1 I suppose ;-) ... I don't know. It's embedded into M1. M1 is this: http://shop1.luftdruckwaechter.de/shop/media/pdf/fa/8d/e9/E-Plan-Luftdruckwaechter-P4-Multi.pdf RLY1 is for example the relay between contacts 3 and 4. In that diagram, M is a ventilation system. That's where I put the multimeter (V) in my diagram. Oh and RLY1 is not given power by M1, it needs an external power source, that's what I meant. I guess I'll remove it in order to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Is the updated diagram not ok?

Comment: @Marki, i give up. i am getting tired of trying to pry information from you. i was trying to figure out if the relay is mechanical or if it is solid state. all you did was post a block diagram of the device. If you refuse to provide adequate information that can be used to answer your question, then you do not deserve the effort from anyone here.

Comment: @jsotola I have given you all the information I have myself, am I a bad person because of that? (I haven't taken the device apart. Yet.) Since you have now asked a concise question yourself my answer is: Since the relay makes the typical "clack" sound when switching, I guess it's electromechanical.

Comment: No, you are not a bad person because of that ... i think that you do not always read the comments that are presented ... i did ask for more information about the relay 3 hours before my "concise question". By the way, my "concise question" is a statement, not a question.

Comment: Since the relay contacts are mechanical, there should be no leakage through the open contacts. I suspect that the device has a snubber circuit across the contacts. That circuit may be responsible for the reading that you get.

Comment: WOW this conversation got pretty messy. I'm with @jsotola. Either it's a solid state relay or there is a snubber in there. The off impedance looks like it is the same order of magnitude as your meter. It's also possible your live and neutral are reversed and the meter is sensitive to show a capacitive measurement.

Comment: If you are able to take a photo of the top or bottom of the controller circuit PCB if may be able to provide the missing information to assist you. What _Chris Stratton_ and _jstola_ have said is the likely cause of your phantom leakage current.

Comment: @jsotola I did read all comments very attentively and tried to edit as a consequence. The problem (as with most StackExchange sites) is that you're supposed to be sort of an expert already before even asking questions. If I was an electrical engineer already I probably wouldn't come here to ask anything.

Back to the topic, I've added new "experiments". I'm afraid this goes into a whole new direction. See the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Measuring apparently fake current.

It appears that you are measuring voltage. If you are using a digital multimeter the inputs are very sensitive as the input impedance (resistance) is in the order of 10 MΩ or more. This means that any capacitive coupling between your dead wire and neighbouring live wires will cause a voltage reading to occur.

> If I now connect some power supply (input 100-240V) where V is connected and instead use V to measure the output voltage of said power supply, there is none. (The power supply has been tested and is working properly.)

This was most confusing. Reading through the comments and question edit what you are saying is, "I connected a small working power supply in place of the meter as a test load and the power supply output was zero." If you had checked the voltage at the *input* to the connected PSU you would have read zero there too. The point is that the stray voltage is very weak and connection of any load to it will cause it to collapse.

[image]

*Figure 1. A Fluke 117 meter with a LO-Z measurement range.*

Interestingly, Fluke have a range of meters with a Lo-Z range to avoid this problem on DC and AC circuits. The input impedance is about 38kΩ (from memory). This is low enough to give a zero reading when measuring voltage on an open circuit even in the presence of 'noise' on adjacent lines. In the absence of one of those you could connect a small light bulb across the terminals. This will load the circuit enough to cause the voltage to collapse.

Comment: You're right about it being voltage and not current of course *sigh* Where would be the relation between the breaker for that circuit being on or off? (see update 1 of the question, no voltage if mains are off) Doesn't that mean that cabling for that same circuit somewhere has to run in parallel for some reason? You're right about the lightbulb test btw.

Comment: Take the same meter reading with the probes held apart in the air. You'll probably get a stray voltage reading. As I said, the meter is very sensitive and you have stray fields all around.